# Matrix multiplication Matlab vs Mathematica

Tags: matlab, matrix, wolfram-mathematica, multiplication

I am trying to identify if Mathematica is as efficient as Matlab in matrix multiplication. 
for example    20000x20000   by 20000x20000
takes 60 sec in Matlab
     300 sec in Mathematica

Do I need to do anything, i.e., turn on parallel computing in Mathematica?

Comment: Can you include the code you are using to measure this? It would be helpful for people trying to replicate your results.

Comment: You should probably also indicate which versions of Matlab and Mathematica you're using too.

Comment: probably has to do with the BLAS implementation in use. Matrix multiplication in MATLAB is likely mapped to `gemm` rountine in BLAS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you will ever get Mathematica to be as fast as Matlab when it comes to dealing with matrices. I actually had to write a Matlab code a while ago that would get data from Mathematica, do some simple operations on the matrices and then feed them back to Mathematica, because doing it within Mathematica itself was taking forever.

Matlab was especially designed to deal with matrices fast, and that's what it does. It's definitely not true of Mathematica, which works beautifully for symbolic calculations but doesn't deal with large datasets/matrices very well.

Comment: probably true, however with mathematica you need to take care to be performing a pure machine precision numerical calculation, and to be using built in matrix operators,  for speed comparison -- which is why its important to see the code.